# How to search in ElasticSearch based on multiple nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am embedding product properties within the product documents and I want to do an aggregation which should return the name of the properties when its value is greater than 0.

How should I compose the query?

=======================================================

The example of the data stored in ElasticSearch:

From the following dataset, I expected results to be: ["Sugar", "Fat"] since no product contains Water

```js
[{
  name: "Product1",
  price: 12.0,
  properties: [
    {
      group: "Product Composition",
      name: "Sugar",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      group: "Product Composition",
      name: "Fat",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      group: "Product Composition",
      name: "Water",
      value: 0
    },
    {
      group: "Packaging",
      name: "Size",
      value: "Big"
    }
  ]
}, {
  name: "Product2",
  price: 11.0,
  properties: [
    {
      group: "Product Composition",
      name: "Sugar",
      value: 0
    },
    {
      group: "Product Composition",
      name: "Fat",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      group: "Product Composition",
      name: "Water",
      value: 0
    },
    {
      group: "Packaging",
      name: "Size",
      value: "Small"
    }
  ]
}]
```

======== Index Mappings ========

```js
{
  "test_products": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "template_1": {
              "path_match": "properties.value",
              "match_mapping_type": "double",
              "mapping": {
                "scaling_factor": 100,
                "type": "scaled_float"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "template_2": {
              "path_match": "properties.value",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "ignore_above": 100,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "properties": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "group": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your mappings of the relevant data so that I can simulate it in my test cluster.

Comment: Hi @apt-get_instal_skill, sorry for the late reply, I have added the index mapping in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will get properties in response> inner hits of  below query

Query:

```
GET test_products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "properties",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "properties.value": {  --> check for value greater than 0
                  "gt": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "properties.group.raw": { ---> remove packaging
                  "value": "Packaging"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}   ----> in response will give matched nested documents
    }
  }
}
```